# How do I increase height of an input field so that placeholder text fully appears in input box HTML5

Tags: html, css

I want to increase height of input box so my placeholder text wraps and is fully viewable to read.  However, my css does not seem to be working!  Any ideas??

Here's the hmtl5 for the screen name

```
<tr>
    <th class='row_header requiredfield'>Screen Name*</th>
    <td><input class="large_width tall_height" id="screen_name" type="text" name="screenname" value="{{screenname}}" placeholder="Put in a name others can understand if you don't want to use your actual name."/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.large_width {
    width:250px;
    height: 25px;
}   

.tall_height {
    height: 50px;
}

input {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

input[placeholder] {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: can u add HTML Code ?

Answer (score 5):

Make height of input and line-height of placeholder same.
For Example

CSS:

```
.input-class
{
  height:30px;
}

.input-class[placeholder]
{
  line-height:30px;
  font-size:22px;
}
```

Comment: but I have other input fields in the template that I don't want as tall --- any other way?

Comment: Now I have edited with particular class value. Give class to input like this <input class="input-class">

Comment: `22pt`? did you mean `px` there? In general using `pt` for anything other than a print style sheet is a big bag of hurt.

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nXWfM/

```
.place {
    height:30px; }

.place[placeholder] {
    font-size:22px; }
```

just set the height of input

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the input box.
That should do it.

```css
#screen_name{
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <th class='row_header requiredfield'>Screen Name*</th>
    <td><input class="large_width tall_height" id="screen_name" type="text" name="screenname" value="{{screenname}}" placeholder="Put in a name others can understand if you don't want to use your actual name."/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to Increase Placeholder/Input Field Height and width in CSS3**
   I have also same problem came now i solved this Question to follows simple code to increase height&width of placeholder/input field

```
input{
height: 25 p x; <!--here height number is how much u want height u will putthat number-->
width: 180 p x; <!--here width number is how much u want width u will put that number-->
```

padding:0 10px;
}
 The above code 100% will works 
    thank u have a nice day